# Unable to convert 4 digit int value to 24 hour time format

Tags: hive, hiveql

My input data format is in the form of 4 digit numbers which represent 24 hour time format. I am trying to find the time difference in minutes between 2 such fields - Expected Arrival Time and Scheduled Arrival Time in minutes. For that I need to convert 4 digit int values to 24 hour time format but I am unable to do so.

I have tried innumerable permutations and combinations but to no avail.

- Expected Arrival time: 1902
- Scheduled Arrival Time: 1806
- Expected result: 56

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two times are **56 minutes**.

Expected Arrival time: 1902 (**07:02 PM**) //2 minutes from 7:00PM

Scheduled Arrival Time: 1806 (**06:06 PM**) //54 minutes to 7:00PM

```
select (unix_timestamp('1902','HHmm') - unix_timestamp('1806',"HHmm"))/60;
+-------+--+
|  _c0  |
+-------+--+
| 56.0  |
+-------+--+
```

(or)

```
select int((unix_timestamp('1902','HHmm') - unix_timestamp('1806',"HHmm"))/60);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 56   |
+------+--+
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but in a few cases I am not able to get the desired result. Like my Field1 is 919 and Field2 is 920, so the difference should be -1. However the code is calculating it as -51. What's weird is of roughly 12 million records, I am seeing this only for 1.6 million records.

Comment: For this case use case statement and compare the length of field1 and field2  **select 
 case 
 when length('919') ='3' then int((unix_timestamp('919','Hmm') - unix_timestamp('920',"Hmm"))/60) 
 when length('9199') ='4' then int((unix_timestamp('1902','HHmm') - unix_timestamp('1806',"HHmm"))/60)
 else null end;**  i have compared for 3,4 digit integers like the same way write all possible case statements and if 3 digit then **Hmm**  if 4 digit then **HH:mm**

Answer (score 0):

```
(t2 / 100) * 60 + t2 % 100
   - (t1 / 100) * 60 - t1 % 100
+ case when t2 < t1 then 1440 else 0 end
```

I'm assuming that the two times can span midnight.